# Load CSS and JS files after the content is loaded via AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery, wordpress, head

i have a Wordpress site that has a "home" and a "photos" page. On the "photos" page, there are specific CSS and JS files that load only on that page.

I am using the Advanced Ajax Page Loader plugin to load the content into a div via AJAX.

So, when I click on the "photos" link on the menu, the new content loads into the div but the CSS and JS files that were supposed to load are not being loaded, because the `<head>` of the document remains the same.

I need to load those CSS and JS files after the content is loaded via AJAX.

Is it possible?

Comment: reload them in ajax success method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute inline JS and CSS after Pageload via AJAX (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143625/execute-inline-js-and-css-after-pageload-via-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Interesting question. But note that researching is faster than asking in 90% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

this function has a parameter for the footer.

For styles it doeSn't matter where they are loaded, i think.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style